# navigating through database columns using arrow keys?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to web development. i'm to make an application using rails 3 now. i cant display the whole table in the index page because there are too many columns. i need a quick way to look through the entire database.

i have the following table:

```
      create_table "fields", :force => true do |t|
        t.string   "basin_name"
        t.string   "basin_type"
        t.string   "area"
        t.string   "prospect_name"
        t.string   "type_of_data_shore"
        t.string   "type_of_processing"
        t.string   "processing_agency_name"
        t.string   "seismic_investigation_number"
        t.string   "field_season"
        t.string   "block_name"
        t.string   "block_type"
        t.string   "sps_format"
        t.string   "input_media"
        t.string   "input_data_location"
        t.integer  "group_interval"
        t.integer  "shot_interval"
        t.string   "active_channels"
        t.decimal  "fold"
        t.decimal  "bin_size"
        t.string   "data_stage"
        t.string   "output_format"
        t.string   "output_media"
        t.string   "output_location"
        t.integer  "volume_of_data_size"
        t.string   "volume_of_data_dimensions"
        t.string   "volume_of_data_type"
        t.date     "date_of_start_of_processing"
        t.date     "date_of_completion_of_processing"
        t.text     "remarks"
        t.text     "problems_faced_and_solutions"
        t.text     "highlights_of_processing"
        t.datetime "created_at",                       :null => false
        t.datetime "updated_at",                       :null => false
        t.integer  "custom_id"
      end
```

is there anyway to navigate from the "show" action of one field to another using just the left and right arrow keys? and the columns should appear based on the "custom_id" column (I dont know javascript either :( )

or is there a better way of doing it through any gem?

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i did well understand, you only need this for the show action, while displaying only one record.

If so, you need to render a large html in show action, but display only a little portion of page at a time, and while navigating, user should NOT make new requests to the server.

```
<div id="field">
  <div id="field_basin_name">..basin_name..</div>
  <div id="field_basin_type" style="display:hidden">..basin_type..</div>
  <div id="field_area" style="display:hidden">..area</div>
  ..
</div>
```

And now you need some javascript, you need to check wich part is shown when user press right or left, hide displayed part and show related part.

I'd go with that logic. Its not really a rails problem, it's mostly a javascript / html.

In my opinion, the most important thing related to rails, is to render the large html only once with show action. Rails part should be very simple. Otherwise it will be too much complicated.

Once you figure out how to handle this, you can find plenty of css / js cosmetics that you can use.

EDIT

If this helps, you can iterate columns of your record with attributes method

```
<% object.attributes.each do |attribute| %>
  <div id="field_<%= attribute_name %>">..</div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: thanks, not the complete answer but set me on the right path :)

Comment: i m glad if helped. added a little additional info.